# Função para pegar coordenadas arraste do mouse

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um paint em java e gostaria de saber como criar uma função que guarde as coordenadas do mouse inicial e final usando o mousePressed e mouseReleased . Grato !

Comment: O que já fez? O que já tentou? Qual a dificuldade?

Answer (score 0):

uma boa mareira seria seria vc criar um class onde vc tera tudo q vc queira salvar , tipo Point, Color, formato , etc . tipo:

```
public class MyPoints
{
    Point pointPressed, pointReleased;

    // faz o constructor(s)
    MyPoints(Point pointPressed,Point pointReleased)
    {
        this.pointPressed = pointPressed;
        this.pointReleased = pointReleased;
    }
    // faca seus getter(s) 
}
```

ai vc cria um ArrayList dessa class ,

```
ArrayList<MyPoints> ar = new ArrayList<>();
```

depois vc pode criar um MouseAdapter e override o

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
```

e o

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)
```

dentro do mousePressed() pega o event e encontre o Point onde foi pressed 
e dentro do mouseReleased pega o event , encontre o Point onde foi released e use

```
ar.add(new MyPoints(pointPressed,pointReleased));
```

agora vc tem um array com seus Points onde ocorreu os events